# How to use generic syntax inside a Razor view file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I was trying to use the following statement:

```
@Html.Test<ISQL>().Nand()
```

However, Razor is choking at the < before the ISQL.

Any official work around for it?

Comment: ...are you missing something because you didn't put that in a code block? I don't see any less than sign...

Answer (score 109, accepted):

To use generic methods you need to escape the expression

```
@(Html.Test<ISQL>().Nand())
```

Answer (score 16):

I just found this question when I was looking for this "same error" when upgrading mvc.

I had :

**Does not work:**

```
@{ 
   ViewBag.Title = "Something " + @Model.Title;
   var something = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Options;    
}
```

Apparently, the syntax went stricter, and as you are inside a @{} block, you should not add @ before Model.Title on the example. But the error on the code editor was pointing to the generic  and it was getting me crazy.

It works fine if there is no <> inside the code, but just removing the @ from Model.Title fix the issue.

**Works:**

```
@{ 
   ViewBag.Title = "Something " + Model.Title;
   var something = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Options;    
}
```

Hope this helps to anyone

Comment: I got crazy too on this one! "The code block is missing a closing } character."

Comment: Thanks. Really helped - a previous @ was causing issues on the next statement, not something you would point directly at.

Answer (score 7):

I had a strange case when I had several assignments inside of one `@{ ... }` bock.

```
@{
    // ... other assignments (without error)
    List<string> stringList = new List<string>()  // ERROR MESSAGE HERE
}
```

What ever I did, there were always errors, like this:

> Using the generic type 'List' requires one type arguments

**The solution**:
I put the assignment line to a **second** `@{ ... }` **bock**.

```
@{
    // ... other assignments
}
@{
    List<string> stringList = new List<string>()  // WORKS
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I appreciate that this 'answer' is somewhat late and the question has obviously been satisfactorily (and well) answered. However, for any future visitors to this page, if you're after a more complete reference guide there's the [MS introduction to Razor syntax](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax) as well as Phil Haack's very useful [Razor quick reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) blog post.

Answer (score 2):

It's about the @ character, this example works before upgrade

```
@{
    string @class = ViewBag.@class;
    IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

After upgrade, it must be separated into two blocks

```
@{  string @class = ViewBag.@class; }
@{  IDictionary<string, object> attrs = new Dictionary<string, object>(); }
```